# IIS Permission Denied 70 error when CGI attempts to Instantiate InternetExplorer.Application

Tags: azure, iis, cgi, 32bit-64bit, dcom

Context: Windows Server 2012 R2 (Azure VM)
IIS: 8.5

The CGI application is a 32bit EXE. It calls the MSScript object to evaluate a JScript script. The JScript attempts to instantiate InternetExplorer.Application. The attempt fails consistently with an permissions error 70.

What is the reason for this and what must I do to get it working? If it really is a permissions error, which permissions need to be adjusted?

**MORE DETAIL**

This is from the Event Viewer (Local), System tab in Windows Logs:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
 and APPID 
{E4803A36-7232-4AC0-A6AF-29D59EBCC303}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\IUSR SID (S-1-5-17) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

**YET MORE**
A posting on [Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/event-id-10016-the-application-specific-permission/9ff8796f-c352-4da2-9322-5fdf8a11c81e) suggests changing the owner of IE from Trusted Installer to Administrator. Is this the answer for me?

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I have seen this the issue was the Application Pool I was using was not correctly set to enable the 32-bit Application.  Once this was modified, going to the advanced settings of the App Pool, it resolved my issue.  I am not sure if the application you are running is dependent upon the App Pool but that is where I would start looking.

Comment: Sadly this is not a solution for me, though it may be for others. In my case the 32-bit Application settings is on.